# Decorator is not working after update 4.0.5 to 4.9.5

Tags: typescript

```
export function TableName(tableName: string, tableDescription: string) {
  return function(constructor: Function) {
    constructor.prototype.tableName = tableName;
    constructor.prototype.tableDescription = tableDescription;
  };
}
```

Property daughters are no longer powered by the class

target es2015

That the class properties are fed and not returned as undefined

Comment: Your english is lacking, and it is not clear at all what you're saying/what your problem is. What are *"property daughters"*? maybe something with inheritance? but what? What do you mean with *"powered by the class"*, powered how? What do you mean with *"properties are fed"* fed to what? and what is returning `undefined`? There's too little context here, your meaning got lost in the translation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.